# Automatic page-flip feature (Page view controller)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm currently doing an app which DISPLAYS tweets one by one (consecutively) using a page view controller. I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_UIPageViewController_Application).

This is a tutorial on how to implement Page view controller without storyboarding.

I want to flip the pages automatically without tapping the iPhone screen and i haven't found any tutorial implementing this type of feature. Is this any way possible?

Please tell me if question is poorly constructed so that i could edit it. Im quite new here.

Comment: The simple way is to use NSTimer for calling the tap function with some specific duration :)

Comment: oh, thank you so much. will give you a feed back once i've done it.

Comment: what tap function should i call? I'm kinda confused. Is the tap function sort of a hidden function? Thanks

Comment: At the time of swipe to change the page you must have call one selector, right? That selector (function) is called in NSTimer. That's it :)

Comment: Sorry for that tap method as there is no kind of method is given or explain in that tutorial you follow so you have no method explicitly defined for controlling the transition. So have to define it or find it out from the tutorial. Sorry, there is no simple way to do it :(